# Android power management scripts

Tags: android, adb

I have recently learned that with the following command

```
fastboot oem off-mode-charge 1
```

you can force a droid device to power on when plugged in instead of going to a charging screen after the device has died.

Is there a command to have the device power down if there is no power. So if I unplug it, I want it to turn off and when the power comes back, I want it to turn on.

Are there scripts I can write and install to handle that for me?

I have attempted to remove the battery from the device, but it seems that the battery completes the circuit.